# Building Dynamic Javascript Object for noUiSlider

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, nouislider

I'm trying to build an object for my noUiSlider range property dynamically in `JavaScript`. Creating a step based range slider requires a `min` and a `max` value, and all the values in between should be a percentage of the total value of items. The following example would create a range slider with 3 steps, 1, 5, and 10.

```
range: {
    'min': 1,
    '50%': 5,
    'max': 10
}
```

My data comes in as follows:

```
[
  {width: "1"},
  {width: "1.5"},
  {width: "2"},
  {width: "3"},
  {width: "4"}
]
```

This array could be any number of `widths`. With my incoming data, I need to format it into an object that my range slider accepts. Something similar to this:

```
{                       {
    'min': 1,               'min': 1,
    '25%': 1.5,             '16.66%': 1.5,
    '50%': 2,      OR       '33.32%': 2,
    '75%': 3,               '49.97%': 3,
    'max': 4                '66.66%': 4,
}                           '83.32%': 5,
                            'max': 6
                        }
```

The `key` value must contain a `min` value as the first item and a `max` value as the last item. The rest of the keys must be calculated as a percentage based on the number of items in the width array, and the values would be `width` value of the array.

I've tried creating the obj with the following code but don't know how to set the first and last key values to `min` and `max`

```
function toObject(arr) {
    var obj = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i)
        if (arr[i] !== undefined) obj[i*10] = arr[i];
    return obj;
}
```

Comment: All you have shown is the goal ... but not any attempts to solve this yourself or really any specific code related problem. This isn't a free code writing service, the objective here is to help you fix **your code**

Comment: Sorry, I've updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about checking the remaining elements as you iterate:

```
function toObject(arr) {
    var obj = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
        var remaining = arr.length - i;
        if (arr[i] !== undefined) {
            if (remaining == arr.length) {
                obj['min'] = arr[i].width;
            }
            else if (remaining === 1) {
                obj['max'] = arr[i].width;
            }
            else {
                obj[(i*10).toString()] = arr[i].width;
            }
        }
    }
    return obj;
}
```

A test from the console:

```
>var a = [
  {width: "1"},
  {width: "1.5"},
  {width: "2"},
  {width: "3"},
  {width: "4"}
];
>
>toObject(a)
{10: "1.5", 20: "2", 30: "3", min: "1", max: "4"}
```

Comment: I need it in this value { string : number }, and 'min' needs to be first where 'max' is last in the object.

Comment: @Romes To get a number as the value, you can wrap the value in `parseInt(value, 10)` like this: `parseInt(arr[i].width, 10)`. As far as order goes, the order of an object is irrelevant since it provides constant time lookup O(1). In other words, you will always be able to get the value you want by calling the key.